# Insert mysql data using javascript and ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Basically I need to insert the value of a textarea asynchronously but when I call the function insertSQLData() it shows the source code of the page, besides that I cant find the other errors. I omitted the database code and any irrelevant code as well.

```
 <?php 
     $q = $_GET["q"];
     $username = $_COOKIE["user"];
 ?>    
  function insertSQLData(str){
    if(str == 0){
        document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "index-async.php?q=+str", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

<form action="" method="get">
<textarea onblur="insertSQLData(this.value);" id="quick-post-form" name="quick-post-form"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="quick-post-btn" id="quick-post-submit">
<div id="holder"></div>
```

```
 if(isset($username) && !empty($q)){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (comment,username) VALUES ('$q', '$username')");
} elseif(!empty($q)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (comment,username) VALUES ('$q', 'Guest User')");
}
```

Comment: it shows the source code of the page no php

Answer (score 0):

You have to load it before your php file starts up.
All you have to do is to write a controller, and use it anywhere instead of your index.php and in that, (after loading those things from DB) redirect user to your index.php page providing those data you need.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you're saying

Comment: I think you have to look at [this](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2005/11/03/mvc%5Fcontroller.html)

Answer (score 0):

So you are calling same page where ajax call is..
obviously it returns the code.

write php code in another file and try to call it.
it works

Answer (score 0):

You write code in conditional statement as per given below.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET["q"]))
        {
             $q = $_GET["q"];
             $username = $_COOKIE["user"];


             if(isset($username) && !empty($q)){
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (comment,username) VALUES ('$q', '$username')");
            } elseif(!empty($q)) {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (comment,username) VALUES ('$q', 'Guest User')");
            }
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
        <script>
         function insertSQLData(str){
            if(str == 0){
                document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML="";
                return;
            }

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "index-async.php?q=+str", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
        <form action="" method="get">
    <textarea onblur="insertSQLData(this.value);" id="quick-post-form" name="quick-post-form"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="quick-post-btn" id="quick-post-submit">
    <div id="holder"></div>
        <?php

        }
?>
```